# How to Capture Changes in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, debezium, oracle-cdc

I followed these steps:

```sh
# Run postgres instance
docker run --name postgres -p 5000:5432 debezium/postgres

# Run zookeeper instance
docker run -it --name zookeeper -p 2181:2181 -p 2888:2888 -p 3888:3888 debezium/zookeeper

# Run kafka instance
docker run -it --name kafka -p 9092:9092 --link zookeeper:zookeeper debezium/kafka

# Run kafka connect
docker run -it --name connect -p 8083:8083 -e GROUP_ID=1 -e CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=my-connect-configs -e OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=my-connect-offsets -e ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=$(echo $DOCKER_HOST | cut -f3  -d'/' | cut -f1 -d':') --link zookeeper:zookeeper --link postgres:postgres --link kafka:kafka debezium/connect

# Open psql console
psql -h localhost -p 5000 -U postgres
CREATE DATABASE inventory;
CREATE TABLE dumb_table(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR);


# Create connector using kafka connect
curl -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" localhost:8083/connectors/ -d '
{
    "name": "inventory-connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "database.hostname": "postgres",
        "database.port": "5432",
        "database.user": "postgres",
        "database.password": "postgres",
        "database.dbname" : "inventory",
        "database.server.name": "dbserver1",
        "database.whitelist": "inventory",
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
        "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.inventory"
    }
}' | jq

# Verify created
curl -H "Accept:application/json" localhost:8083/connectors/ | jq

# Verify configuration
curl -X GET -H "Accept:application/json" localhost:8083/connectors/inventory-connector | jq


# Start a console viewer on kafka

docker run -it --name watcher --rm --link zookeeper:zookeeper debezium/kafka watch-topic -a -k dbserver1.public.dumb_table
```

```sql
# Verify the existence of replication slot in postgres 
SELECT slot_name, plugin, slot_type, database, active, restart_lsn, confirmed_flush_lsn 
FROM pg_replication_slots;
```

But at the end of these steps, I only see the error log messages in debezium terminal. How can I see the all log messages?

Comment: And what error message do you see?

Comment: STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO dumb_table VALUES (11,'B');
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "dumb_table_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(11) already exists.
STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO dumb_table VALUES (11,'C');
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "dumb_table_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(12) already exists.
STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO dumb_table VALUES (12,'C');

Comment: but when I added rows susccesfully , I dont see any log messages.

Comment: In psql command you use port 5000. In Debezium reqistration request you use 5432. Is it correct?

Can you share your log file?

Answer (score 0):

## Open psql console

psql -h localhost -p 5000 -U postgres

CREATE DATABASE inventory;

After this statement, you need to connect to the inventory Database which you just created as postgres is the default DB.

In psql prompt type:

```
\c inventory
```

This will connect to the inventory DB.

After connecting you now CREATE the table as below:

```
CREATE TABLE dumb_table(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR);
```

Now Issue some insert commands on the same table under same DB i.e inventory

```
INSERT INTO dumb_table VALUES (1, 'VALUE1');
```

You will be able to see changes in the consumer console.

**As you are creating a debezium connector for listening to the changes on inventory database. Therefore it only listens to the changes(Insert/Update/Delete) of the tables created under the inventory database.**